# Best way to add same property to two classes

Tags: c#

I have a class structure like so:

```
public class Base
{
  public string PropBase { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base 
{
  public string PropDerived { get; set; }
}
```

Now these classes are used in the webapi controllers and one action returns a `Base` and another `Derived`.

I want to have another controller that would have the same action structure (and would return two models), but i want to add another property to both of these.

I thought of having something like

```
public class BaseSpecific : Base
{
  public string Common { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedSpecific : Derived
{
  public string Common { get; set; }
}
```

But this doesn't look DRY to me.

I don't really want to use the more specific `Derived` class for both actions because it muddles the intent of the code.

What's the best way to do this?

P.S. The example is over-simplified, of course. The controllers live in two different projects, and the models live in a nuget package shared across the two.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to add a common property to the base Class  because its not relevant to original controller actions?

Comment: @Saruman that's correct

Comment: It is difficult to make a recommendation without more context. If we're just talking about anemic models that have no behavior, I would avoid using inheritance to begin with, since you can accomplish everything you need with interfaces, and more (e.g. multiple interfaces and generic variance).

Comment: @JohnWu then what, have multiple implementations of said interfaces, again violating DRY?

Comment: @zaitsman Or if you are really worried, make one god like super duper object, and expose interfaces for you to work with not cluttering and causing your OCD to fire. however, the thing is and quite honestly, for models and Dtos and things of this nature you are better of making a new class with exactly what you need, it makes life easier if requirements change

Comment: @zaitsman Yes, if we are talking about dumb models. In fact in 95% of cases there's no need for an interface either. Just declare the autoproperty in both classes and use it in both action methods. You have to have a reason to use inheritance, don't just assume you need it.

Comment: @JohnWu in this case the reason is that the second action is a more specific representation of the same object (with more properties)

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be some confusion over what DRY really means. DRY isn't concerned directly with code duplication - that is merely a symptom. DRY is concerned with the duplication of *business logic*. It's entirely possible to duplicate business logic with duplicate, or completely different, code (e.g. having 3 different ways of logging users into your application).

The most important question you can ask yourself for problems like this is: should these two (or more) things be able to vary independently? For example, if I change the behaviour of `x`, should `y`'s behaviour also change? If the answer is `no`, then they are conceptually different things.

Just because the properties are coincidentally the same at the moment, doesn't mean they represent violations of DRY. If they have different responsibilities, they just happen to be the same at the time of writing.

Preferring composition over inheritance is what allows your types to vary independently from one another. Inheritance leads to problems such as the one you have now, where you really want `BaseSpecific` to vary in a different way to `DerivedSpecific`, but you're preventing those types from doing so as they are built on top of `Base`. Composition also allows you to reuse more logic in other scenarios, too, which promotes a more malleable structure in your application.

The solution? Split up your types. Don't share the properties, because `BaseSpecific` and `DerivedSpecific` are already telling you they want to vary independently.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I've worked with several cases of "coincidental DRY" that have caused major problems when changes needed to be made to one implementation and not the other.

Comment: Well, they don’t actually. They describe the same mode, and derived has more info about it then base. But in another project i have all the same properties and then some, and THOSE belong to both base and derived.

Comment: @zaitsman The problem eventually becomes: why put anything on `Derived` when it can be added to `Base`? The longer that goes on, the more convoluted `Base` becomes, which then further decreases `Derived`'s value. Rather than doing that, for each additional controller action, add a model that aggregates the class you want to use and adds the property you need, and return that instead. Those types can then vary independently of anything else.

Comment: No it doesn’t. You put stuff on derived that frontend renders in ‘details’ view.

Comment: @zaitsman Details views are typically built up of aggregated data. For example, imagine you're looking at buying a car and you visit the details view for a particular car you've seen. That view could aggregate different pieces of data, such as make/model data, tax data, repair/service history, etc. Each of those things could be used in isolation. All you'd need to query those would be a registration number, but, when composed, they can still vary independently.

Comment: Except they will come across multiple network calls and multiple database reads?

Comment: @zaitsman Multiple database reads, but not necessarily multiple network calls. However, microservice architecture would likely perform aggregation that way, as would angular/react-type apps.

Answer (score 0):

Something that you can do is create another class and make these two classes extend the implementations of your new class. That way they will inherit the property from the extended class, and it will still look robust

Now that I think about it more, instead of deriving, why don't you create an object inside Base instead? Such as
public Derived ObjDerived { get; set; }

Comment: but that new class won't be able to derive from both `specific` and `base`?

Comment: You can define your new class as you like, it is a mere assistant to what you want to accomplish, a derived class is simply a class including the deriving object as a subobject; you can have a nested derivation: (included in EDIT)

Answer (score 0):

As i'm sure you already know, C# (.Net) has no multiple inheritance.

You need to either have derived middle versions of your base classes, use an interface (which is not really going to solve anything), or just recreate your base classes altogether

No free lunch today sorry

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually really, really easy. If it's just a property, add it to both classes and don't worry about inheritance at all.

I would avoid using inheritance as means to share common properties across classes that otherwise serve different purposes. Eventually it leads to more and more layers of classes, and sooner a later a class ends up with a property that it doesn't need because we wanted to inherit A, B, and C, and we can't do that without inheriting D also.

Suppose you have two or more properties that have a common meaning or purpose across multiple classes that are otherwise different. In that case you could compose those properties into a separate class, like

```
public class RecordStatus
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated{ get; set; }
}
```

Then different classes can have an instance of that as a property. There's still no need for them to inherit it. The use of the common class just serves to communicate that this property has a common meaning wherever it appears. It also prevents the extra effort of adding multiple properties to classes. Now you can just add one.

When you just need to re-use properties or methods across classes, composition is a better approach. Put properties or methods in classes and then add instances of those classes where needed.

Inheritance works better in cases where an object is going to be downcast. Perhaps in some methods you want to deal with derived classes differently, but in others you want to have a collection of the base class and operate on them without caring about the derived classes.

Even then you might not need to use inheritance. Perhaps you could have the classes implement a common interface. Perhaps in situations where you need different classes to implement a common interface you could wrap them in another class that implements the interface and adapts the inner class to the outer interface. Either of those approaches avoid taking two or more unrelated classes and coupling them by having them inherit from a common base.

Many people have found that the cases where inheritance is useful are fewer than they first thought. I've seen what looked like clear-cut cases for inheritance get out of control after just a few changes as the derived classes have less and less in common and the tree-like structure turns into a bush or a web.

Answer (score 0):

Without talking of inheritance, you just seem to want to add a property when returning from your controller, I assume as a serialized value

If you really need to add some property in your answer, you could do this:

```
    public class Base
    {
        public string PropBase { get; set; }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public string PropDerived { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(SpecificConverter))]
    [DataContract]
    public class Specific
    {
        public Specific(object obj)
        {
            Object = obj;
        }
        public bool Common { get; set; }

        public object Object { get; set; }
    }

    public class SpecificConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            Specific obj = value as Specific;
            JToken t = JToken.FromObject(obj.Object);
            t.First.AddBeforeSelf(new JProperty("Common", obj.Common));
            t.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(Specific).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, simply return a `new Specific(myObject)` (or make some extension method) from your onto return the correct serialized value from your controller

returning a Derived object:

```
{"PropDerived":"derived","PropBase":"base"}
```

Returning a Specific from previous derived:

```
{"Common":"common","PropDerived":"derived","PropBase":"base"}
```

You could make the same for xml or other if you need other serialization format

I assume it's possible to use Specific which have a T object, but this is more troublesome because of  `Specific obj = value as Specific;`
You can easily with dynamic and this will work

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SpecificConverter))]
[DataContract]
public class Specific<T>
{
    public Specific(T obj)
    {
        Object = obj;
    }
    public string Common { get; set; } = "common";

    public T Object { get; set; }
}
...
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    dynamic dyn = value;
    JToken t = JToken.FromObject(dyn.Object);
    t.First.AddBeforeSelf(new JProperty("Common", dyn.Common));
    t.WriteTo(writer);
}
...
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    return typeof(Specific<>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
}
...
public static class SepcificHelper
{
    public static Specific<T> ToSpecific<T>(T obj)
    {
        return new Specific<T>(obj);
    }
}
```

And just return "myDerived.ToSpecific()"

If common property is the same on whole controller, you can also set a specific serializer on your controller, just return your object and do the operation in the specificSerializer